# Can mobile device bluetooth mac address be changed?

Tags: java-me, mobile, bluetooth

Can mobile device bluetooth mac address be changed??
I am asking this because one part of my system depends on this security. If it can be done, how hard is this to do and how one can do that.

I know that on linux you can change it pretty easily, but that is for PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device manufacturers will not allow changing of MAC address, 
MAC address is controlled and allocated by IEEE since it has to be unique.

if you are a device manufacturer you can get a bunch of addresses and keep changing them on a single device. (so theoretically is it possible)
Changing MAC is possible by the lower level drivers and typically this capability is not exposed to applications.

Answer (score 1):

"I am asking this because one part of my system depends on this security." 
If you are basing MAC address of blue tooth as a security consideration you are going about this the wrong way.

This is the EXACT same as banks relying on just the hotsname "back.com" to verify that the user is connecting to correct website. This is why https and SSL was invented not only for encryption but also to verify that users are who they say they are.

IE you will need to implement some sort of trust chain in order for this to be secure not some random MAC address which is technically publicly viewable (with in range) and also spoofable as has been proven by PC application/drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of any tools on Windows that can do it, only Linux.  I suggest you get a Live CD of Linux and follow this walkthrough:

http://www.siddharthabbineni.com/tech/hardware/change-bluetooth-device-mac-address.html